# ssh to a new 'vagrant up' doesn't work until after the first time I run vagrant ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, vagrant

When I just start up a new vagrant evn. 
I can't ssh directly into the boxes until I do a `vagrant ssh`.
Then I can ssh directly with out a problem.

In the auth logs I see the following errors

`Sep  5 14:24:24 node2 sshd[1798]: Connection closed by authenticating user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 59816 [preauth]`

Which is probably some configuration that is preventing this from working.

```
 ssh  vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2204
 Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2204' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 vagrant@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Ssh with debug

```
 ssh -v vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2204
 OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
 debug1: Reading configuration data /home/aaron/.ssh/config
 debug1: /home/aaron/.ssh/config line 14: Applying options for 127.0.0.1
 debug1: /home/aaron/.ssh/config line 69: Applying options for *
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2204.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /home/aaron/.ssh/ansible_id_rsa type 0
 debug1: identity file /home/aaron/.ssh/ansible_id_rsa-cert type -1
 debug1: identity file /home/aaron/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
 debug1: identity file /home/aaron/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
 debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:2204 as 'vagrant'
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:dkycbxm6Tr8t45KCUiMbAauvQTtw6+go3sss3nk+nrY
 debug1: checking without port identifier
 Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2204' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: Will attempt key: /home/aaron/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:RVSwD4SH/PoB+hUiP/wjyEtb+CST8QgPPNl3SO3zuBg explicit agent
 debug1: Will attempt key: /home/aaron/.ssh/ansible_id_rsa RSA SHA256:iIXdS4I0sfQFx+Hlb3EtA4iMZDaKVvTDP1Cwj2MUohI explicit agent
 debug1: Will attempt key:  RSA SHA256:XBZaVosr5ppZecW61cMWfduIETMDKrjAfVle2vaU6Uk agent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Offering public key: /home/aaron/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:RVSwD4SH/PoB+hUiP/wjyEtb+CST8QgPPNl3SO3zuBg explicit agent
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: Offering public key: /home/aaron/.ssh/ansible_id_rsa RSA SHA256:iIXdS4I0sfQFx+Hlb3EtA4iMZDaKVvTDP1Cwj2MUohI explicit agent
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: Offering public key:  RSA SHA256:XBZaVosr5ppZecW61cMWfduIETMDKrjAfVle2vaU6Uk agent
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
 vagrant@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Vagrant up terminal output

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'mgmt' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> mgmt: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' version '20190828.0.0' is up to date...
==> mgmt: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> mgmt: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> mgmt: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    mgmt: Adapter 1: nat
    mgmt: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> mgmt: Forwarding ports...
    mgmt: 22 (guest) => 2202 (host) (adapter 1)
==> mgmt: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> mgmt: Booting VM...
==> mgmt: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    mgmt: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
    mgmt: SSH username: vagrant
    mgmt: SSH auth method: private key
==> mgmt: Machine booted and ready!
==> mgmt: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    mgmt: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    mgmt: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    mgmt: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    mgmt: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    mgmt: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    mgmt: your host and reload your VM.
    mgmt: 
    mgmt: Guest Additions Version: 5.2.32
    mgmt: VirtualBox Version: 6.0
==> mgmt: Setting hostname...
==> mgmt: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> mgmt: Mounting shared folders...
    mgmt: /vagrant => /run/media/aaron/nixdata/Source/ansible-docker/vagrant/swarm
==> mgmt: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> mgmt: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> node1: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' version '20190828.0.0' is up to date...
==> node1: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> node1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> node1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    node1: Adapter 1: nat
    node1: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> node1: Forwarding ports...
    node1: 22 (guest) => 2203 (host) (adapter 1)
==> node1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> node1: Booting VM...
==> node1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    node1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2203
    node1: SSH username: vagrant
    node1: SSH auth method: private key
==> node1: Machine booted and ready!
==> node1: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    node1: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    node1: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    node1: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    node1: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    node1: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    node1: your host and reload your VM.
    node1: 
    node1: Guest Additions Version: 5.2.32
    node1: VirtualBox Version: 6.0
==> node1: Setting hostname...
==> node1: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> node1: Mounting shared folders...
    node1: /vagrant => /run/media/aaron/nixdata/Source/ansible-docker/vagrant/swarm
==> node1: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> node1: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> node2: Importing base box 'ubuntu/bionic64'...
==> node2: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> node2: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' version '20190828.0.0' is up to date...
==> node2: Setting the name of the VM: swarm_node2_1567690918350_55935
==> node2: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> node2: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    node2: Adapter 1: nat
    node2: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> node2: Forwarding ports...
    node2: 22 (guest) => 2204 (host) (adapter 1)
==> node2: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> node2: Booting VM...
==> node2: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    node2: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2204
    node2: SSH username: vagrant
    node2: SSH auth method: private key
    node2: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    node2: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    node2: 
    node2: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    node2: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    node2: 
    node2: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    node2: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    node2: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> node2: Machine booted and ready!
==> node2: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    node2: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    node2: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    node2: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    node2: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    node2: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    node2: your host and reload your VM.
    node2: 
    node2: Guest Additions Version: 5.2.32
    node2: VirtualBox Version: 6.0
==> node2: Setting hostname...
==> node2: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> node2: Mounting shared folders...
    node2: /vagrant => /run/media/aaron/nixdata/Source/ansible-docker/vagrant/swarm
==> node2: Running provisioner: shell...
    node2: Running: inline script
    node2: hello from node2 worker
```

Extract from the auth log /var/log/auth.

```
Sep  5 13:41:24 node2 systemd-logind[842]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Sep  5 13:41:24 node2 systemd-logind[842]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Sep  5 13:41:24 node2 systemd-logind[842]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Sep  5 13:41:24 node2 systemd-logind[842]: New seat seat0.
Sep  5 13:41:24 node2 sshd[995]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep  5 13:41:24 node2 sshd[995]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep  5 13:41:28 node2 sshd[1216]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 58726 ssh2: RSA SHA256:1ZgLBFBYfTGKpryguu9GYmEYe7jw5DVr3qAVEpmi+jQ
Sep  5 13:41:28 node2 sshd[1216]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:28 node2 systemd-logind[842]: New session 1 of user vagrant.
Sep  5 13:41:28 node2 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:30 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:30 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:30 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:40 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:41 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -l
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 13:41:42 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 13:42:43 node2 sshd[1216]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user vagrant
Sep  5 13:42:43 node2 systemd-logind[842]: Removed session 1.
Sep  5 13:42:43 node2 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user vagrant
Sep  5 14:00:26 node2 sshd[1777]: Connection closed by authenticating user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 59192 [preauth]
Sep  5 14:08:22 node2 sshd[1780]: Connection closed by authenticating user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 59362 [preauth]
Sep  5 14:08:40 node2 sshd[1783]: Connection closed by authenticating user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 59382 [preauth]
Sep  5 14:17:01 node2 CRON[1786]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  5 14:17:01 node2 CRON[1786]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep  5 14:20:21 node2 sshd[1795]: Connection closed by authenticating user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 59798 [preauth]
Sep  5 14:24:24 node2 sshd[1798]: Connection closed by authenticating user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 59816 [preauth]
Sep  5 14:24:32 node2 sshd[1800]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 59820 ssh2: RSA SHA256:1ZgLBFBYfTGKpryguu9GYmEYe7jw5DVr3qAVEpmi+jQ
Sep  5 14:24:32 node2 sshd[1800]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)
Sep  5 14:24:32 node2 systemd-logind[842]: New session 4 of user vagrant.
Sep  5 14:24:32 node2 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)
Sep  5 14:24:48 node2 sudo:  vagrant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/vagrant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
Sep  5 14:24:48 node2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by vagrant(uid=0)
Sep  5 14:26:02 node2 sshd[1938]: Postponed publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 59824 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep  5 14:26:02 node2 sshd[1938]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 10.0.2.2 port 59824 ssh2: RSA SHA256:1ZgLBFBYfTGKpryguu9GYmEYe7jw5DVr3qAVEpmi+jQ
Sep  5 14:26:02 node2 sshd[1938]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)
Sep  5 14:26:02 node2 systemd-logind[842]: New session 6 of user vagrant.
Sep  5 14:26:04 node2 sshd[2004]: Received disconnect from 10.0.2.2 port 59824:11: disconnected by user
Sep  5 14:26:04 node2 sshd[2004]: Disconnected from user vagrant 10.0.2.2 port 59824
Sep  5 14:26:04 node2 sshd[1938]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user vagrant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some changes to my vagrant file. 
Specifically not using `box = 'ubuntu/bionic64'`, and using the recommended `box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04`

### The [bento project](https://app.vagrantup.com/bento)

> These boxes are built using templates from the Chef's Bento project. Should you find any bugs, please open an issue or send a pull request. Thanks!

They worked as expected at startup, I could ssh.

This [vlogger](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMWwct3_kb-358XZdnN66zb3HaU97DSQ0) recommends only using the hashicorp or bento project images for vagrant. As they tend to work better and have better support. In my case that seams to be the case.